# Eclipse Indigo unable to run PHP page on external web browser

Tags: php, debugging, xampp, xdebug, eclipse-indigo

I have setup **XDebug** in **xampp** and in **Eclipse Indigo**. When I am trying to run the PHP web page from eclipse it isn't showing any output ! or it isn't opening a new tab in Firefox 8. I have configured Eclipse indigo to use external browser from *Window* → *Preferences* → *General* → *Web Browser*.

At my home this configuration works perfectly fine. Its only at my office I face this problem. I am sitting behind a proxy so I configured **XDebug** to use the proxy which my web browser is using. There is one attribute IDE Key which I am not aware of! Can anyone please help me out on this ?

Another point is does the ADT plug-in have anything to do with the functioning of the PDT plug-in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem got solved. Port 9000 was in some use. I changed the port and it worked ! :)